# Craft 3: Can't backup database ("mysqldump: command not found")

Tags: database

I just tried to export the DB on the Database Backup page. Unfortunately, I got an error message saying **"There was a problem backing up your database. Please check the Craft logs."**

So I checked the logs, and found this...

> Could not create backup: The shell command "mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/mysite/storage/runtime/temp/my.cnf... failed with exit code 127: sh: mysqldump: command not found...

(There's more to that error message, but I'm hoping that all the relevant parts are included here.)

**What am I missing?** It seems like I still need to install something else, is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Craft 3 did away with the PHP-based database backup solution that Craft 2 utilized (for many reasons).

Now it requires that the [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) executable (if you're using MySQL) or [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) executable (if you're using PostgreSQL) is available to PHP in order to do backups.  This is usually just a matter of including the path to that executing in your PATH environment variable.

There is also the [`backupCommand`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/config/GeneralConfig.php#L111) config setting that you can use to override Craft's default backup implementation if you have some other backup solution you'd like to use.

Same for [`restoreCommand`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/config/GeneralConfig.php#L553).

Related issue here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1369

Comment: Hi @brad, I used mariadb (via homebrew) and added the path to .bash_profile and it still wouldn't work. Neither works (export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.13/bin or
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.13/bin:$PATH). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly this issue; mariadb on OSX via homebrew; path added to .bash_profile, doesn't work.