# Back-up doesn't work in Craft CMS 3 on MAMP locally

Tags: craft3, database, mamp, back-up

I installed Craft CMS 3.0.1 locally on MAMP (Apache/PHP7.0.22), but when I want to do a backup of the database it says:
"There was a problem backing up your database. Please check the Craft logs. Back-up van database".
I cound not find any logs that pin pointed the problem. How does this happen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have just run into a similar problem.

I'm not sure if this is what fixed it but try creating an Envvars file as per jonlivingstone's comment here https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2364

Once I had done that my backup ran. I then had to switch MAMP out of FastCGI mode otherwise I got a 500 error at the end of the update process.

Comment: The Envvars file fixed it for me too once I also ran the following command in terminal: sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump /usr/local/bin/mysqldump as per https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1369#issuecomment-279102527 See https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/craft-3-cant-backup-database for similar issue with explanation of Craft 3 backup differences