# Craft 3 : Can't backup database ("failed with exit code -1")

Tags: craft3, database, back-up

I can't backup database, the log says :

> [error][yii\base\Exception] yii\base\Exception: Could not create
>   backup: The shell command "mysqldump {{...blablabla...}} failed with
>   exit code -1. in
>   /home/user/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php:38

Any ideas what error -1 means ?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of [that other question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/23290/45). I've added the error message to both question titles, in order to show the distinction.

Comment: Have you added `mysqldump` to your PATH environment variable?  If so, was it a user based PATH or a whole system PATH variable?

Comment: `which mysqldump` gives `/usr/bin/mysqldump` does that help ?