# Setting up Craft 3 database backup command for a remote database server

Tags: control-panel, database, mysql, back-up

I have my Craft 3 database on a separate server than my Craft webserver (load balancing) and when I use the download database backup function in Craft 3, it doesn't know where to look.

I haven't worked with a setup with separate locations for the DB and the site before so it's something new for me to work with.

From [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/craft-3-cant-backup-database-mysqldump-command-not-found/23291#23291), I think it's where I'd setup a custom `backupCommand` config, but I don't know where to start.

It's on an nginx setup if that helps?

Cheers.

Comment: might help: [Mitigating Disaster via Website Backups](https://nystudio107.com/blog/mitigating-disaster-via-website-backups)

Comment: You always have something, Andrew. Gonna get setup with this 

Comment: @Jay Be sure and add an answer when you get a working solution. :)